# Handling json data using jQuery sent by using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**I have tried searching all possible matches of my problem and also have tried a couple of solutions but unfortunately none worked**
  My backend code:

```
Person p;
        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            p = new Person();
            p.id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["Id"]);
            p.name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            p.phone = Convert.ToInt64(dr["Phone"]);

            pList.Add(p);
        }
        string ans = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pList, Formatting.Indented);
```

jQuery.ajax

```
function ShowData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/Data",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                    var list = { "Person": +data };
                    for (i = 0; i < list.Person.length; i++) {
                        alert('Id: ' + list.Person[i].Id + '/nName: ' + list.Person[i].Name + '/nPhone: ' + list.Person[i].Phone);
                        console.log('Id: ' + list.Person[i].Id + '/nName: ' + list.Person[i].Name + '/nPhone: ' + list.Person[i].Phone);
                    }
                    console.log(list.Person.length);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
```

Alert output

```
[

  {

    "id": 1,

    "name": "Bhavik",

    "phone": 9601109585

  },

  {

    "id": 2,

    "name": "Xyz",

    "phone": 1234567890

  },

  {

    "id": 3,

    "name": "Abc",

    "phone": 9876543210

  }

]
```

`console.log(list.Person.length);` returns undefined and hence does not enters the for loop.. So to work out with it.. and why is it necessary to specify `contentType` while `dataType` already exist.. Also can I use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of $.ajax.

Comment: From your `alert`, it looks like `{"Person": +data}` should be `{"Person": data.d}`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  should change your code to be var list = {"Person": data.d}; to reflect what you're alerting.

```
function ShowData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/Data",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                    var list = { "Person": +data.d };
                    for (i = 0; i < list.Person.length; i++) {
                        alert('Id: ' + list.Person[i].Id + '/nName: ' + list.Person[i].Name + '/nPhone: ' + list.Person[i].Phone);
                        console.log('Id: ' + list.Person[i].Id + '/nName: ' + list.Person[i].Name + '/nPhone: ' + list.Person[i].Phone);
                    }
                    console.log(list.Person.length);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Just to add a little to your answer, placing the `+` in front of a variable will retrieve the integer value of that variable: (`+'123'` becomes `123`).  If the variable is not a valid integer (`abc123`), you will get back `NaN`.  What the OP has created in `list` will look like `{"Person":NaN}`.

Comment: @Rooster shit man what a mistake.. I thought like code in C# and added `+` to concatenate.. Done man.. Thanks.. But than `list.Person.length` will count the char and I need only to count the set of answer that must be 3 here.. Any ideas..

Comment: @Bhavik remove the + and set the contents of list using an if to check to make sure data.d is what you want.  like if(typeof data.d === 'object'){var list = { "Person": data.d };}else{var list = {};}   or something like that??

Answer (score 0):

Also this should be a GET request not a post, then you would be able to use $.getJSON.

Comment: I tried using `$.parseJSON` but it didn't worked.. And do you mean that $.getJSON works with GET only.. Thanks

Comment: actually when you declare a dataType = json it expects a json in return and attempts to parse it.

Comment: @Rooster you said `it attempts to parse it` but is it necessary that it does it all times.. Because my experience says something else [Check my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755523/looping-within-list-using-jquery/).. Hope I am not wrong..